# How to distort an Image in OpenCV?

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv

I see that there are several ways to distort an image. like...Circle, Diffuse, Marble, Ripple, Twirl, Water, ...

I have come across some ipl functions like, iplRotateCenter(), iplWarpAffine(), iplShear() etc. does OpenCV have any such functions? if i need to use the ipl library in opencv, how to do it?

Comment: You are asking two independent questions, consider dividing them into two StackOverflow questions. (1. How to distort in OpenCV..., 2. How to call IPL from OpenCV...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open CV has such functions.
Old openCV (C inreface), methods like cvWarpPerspective(), cvRemap(), cvLogPolar()
New openCV (C++ inreface), methods like warpPerspective(), remap(),...